# fopen / ofstream::open fail when creating a BMP file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, fopen, bmp

Years ago I created a C++ function using FILE to create bitmap files.  Recently (not sure when or why) this code is now failing when opening the file.  The problem is with the open call ...

```
file_ptr = fopen("ScreenShots/Screenshot1.bmp", "wb");
```

Currently this results in an error 13, permission denied error.  Change the filename extension to something else and the fopen works fine.  For example,

```
file_ptr = fopen("ScreenShots/Screenshot1.bm2", "wb");
```

The file saves correctly and when changing the extension back to BMP I can display the file correctly in Paintshop.

Did a quick check using ofstream and same problem.

Any ideas why I get a permission denied error when trying to open BMP files to write data?  For information I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 on Windows 10.

To give the complete section of code ...

```
BITMAPFILEHEADER bitmap_header;
BITMAPINFOHEADER bitmap_info;
FILE *file_ptr;
unsigned int count;
unsigned char tempRGB;
char filename[256];
bool finished;


// CREATE A UNIQUE FILENAME

count = 1;
finished = false;

do
{
    // CREATE NAME

    sprintf(filename, "ScreenShots/Screenshot%d.bmp", count);


    // CHECK IF FILE EXISTS

    errno = 0;
    file_ptr = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (file_ptr)
    {
        // FILE EXISTS

        fclose(file_ptr);
        count = count + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // UNIQUE FILENAME

        file_ptr = fopen(filename, "wb");
        if (file_ptr == NULL)
        {
            // UNABLE TO OPEN FOR WRITING - GIVE UP
            // (USING OWN LOGGING CLASS)

            jalog.log("\nERROR on Screenshot >");
            jalog.log(filename);
            jalog.log("< >");
            jalog.log((short)errno);

            return;
        }

        finished = true;
    }
}
while (finished == false);
```

Comment: Are you really *sure* about the open-mode flags? You know that the `"r"` is for ***reading***?

Comment: Opening in read mode usually doesn't _create_ any files.

Comment: My mistake ... copied the wrong bit of code!!  The first line should have read ... file_ptr = fopen("ScreenShots/Screenshot1.bmp", "wb");

Comment: @JonAlma Well, you can [edit] your question, and if you're on it I'd recommend you post a [mcve] as required here..

Comment: Could be that the file already exists, and permissions prevent it from being written to, so the fopen fails.

Comment: The file I am trying to write to is always a new one - I have a check on existing filenames to make sure I don't overwrite existing files.  I have added the complete code (to trying to open the new file to write) in my original post.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but usually the state of `errno` is undefined unless the *previous* call failed. I do not know what your `jalog.log` functions does, but they might cause the value to become thus undefined and indeterminate. I suggest you save the value of `errno` immediately after `fopen` fails and use this saved value when logging it..

Comment: You are looking at a relative path `"ScreenShots/Screenshot%d.bmp"`, make sure there is `"ScreenShots"` directory in that path. Or use full path name.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to find the issue ... Avast antivirus.  I noticed that trying to do an open action for a BMP file took a few seconds while opening any other file type (successfully or unsuccessfully) was instantaneous.  As something similar happens when running new programs I tried disabling all the Avast shields and I could successfully create a BMP file using the existing code.

For my own personal use I can whitelist my own programs, but annoying if I get to distributing the program to other people.

Thanks for the help ... and sorry for raising a C++ issue that in the end had nothing to do with C++!

Comment: After losing an hour on the same issue, I know how it feels. That said, you can whitelist a root folder (say "examples") and all programs there will have access, even if they are in subfolders.